# Rounding to the nearest term in a geometric progression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algorithms, logarithms

Consider the following progression:

$$R(i)=5\cdot10^{\frac{i}{30}}$$

where $i$ is ith number within the progression.

I would like to devise an equation that will round input value to the nearest number from this progression.

For example 5th, 6th, and 7th numbers in this progression are:

```
R(5) = 7.338996338
R(6) = 7.92446596231
R(7) = 8.55664152074
```

And the 'rounding' equation T(x) should produce:

```
T(7.45) = 7.338996338
T(8) = 7.92446596231 
T(8.424523535) = 8.55664152074
```

Can anyone point me at the right direction for solving this? Is there any general methods for such things?

**Important requirement**: I don't want to use lookup tables.

Comment: The rounding equation expected results seem completely random to me. I can't get it by induction.

Comment: It seems $T(8)$ is the number in the progression nearest to $8$.  And so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty easy:

Basically you are looking for the integer $i$, so that
$$5\cdot 10^{\frac{i}{30}} \approx x$$

, where $x$ is the input value. By dividing by 5, taking the power of 30, and using log, we get.

$$10^{\frac{i}{30}}\approx \frac{x}5 \\ 10^i \approx \left(\frac{x}{5}\right)^{30} \\ i\approx \log_{10}\left(\left(\frac x5\right)^{30}\right)=30\cdot\log_{10}\left(\frac x5\right)$$
If you want to round to the nearest term, just calculate i using this formula. i will be most likely irrational, so take the floor(i) and ceil(i) and look if R(floor(i)) or R(ceil(i)) is nearer to your input x.

---

For instance: Your input is $x=8$:

$$i\approx 30\cdot\log_{10}\left(\frac85\right)=6.123$$
So you try if $R(6)$ or $R(7)$ is nearer to $8$, $R(6)$ is nearer, so $T(8) = 7.92446$

---

**NOTE:** Your function $R$ is not linear. So you really have to compare R(floor(i)) and R(ceil(i)), not only floor(i) and ceil(i). There are cases, when the input $x$ is nearer to R(floor(i)), but i is nearer to ceil(i).